# What's the best graphic in R to study air pollution?

Tags: python, r

I have a Python dataframe (in addition to an excel file) with data on air pollution for countries, (one line every day between 2014 and 2020). I would like to see what's the polluant the most related to industrial production, fort that I want to compare the data during quarantine and after.

These are the first lines of my excel file (also a python dataframe)

[image]

I am new to Python/R as well as statistics and I do not really know how to handle this data and what type of graphic I should use ?

Any information is welcome

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just start with simple line graph. Each line in graph will represent Specie. The X axis will be years from your data and Y axis will be the median. I am not sure why you have median and not actual data but this is how you can chart with visualization. Use this [link](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/time-series.html) to start.